# What is the probability a difference of two appears before 3?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, dice

Given a sequence of trials, where each trial is rolling two dice, each trial's outcome is the absolute difference between the values on the die. What is the probability that the outcome of 2 occurs before the outcome of 3?

My solution:
There are 8 combinations with a difference of two {(1,3), (2,4), (3,5), (4,6), (3,1), (4,2), (5,3), (6,4)}, so would the probability just be 8/36?

Comment: No - $\frac{8}{36}$ is the probability of a difference of $2$ on the first roll.  You have not taken into account the probability of a difference of $3$, or of some other difference

Comment: This question is not clear. It could be: "Given a _sequence_ of trials, where each trial is rolling two dice, each trial's outcome is the _absolute_ difference between the values on the die. What is the probability that the outcome of 2 occurs before the outcome of 3?" - ambiguity in the question needs to be resolved before it can be answered.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question.

Comment: Hint: Your formula doesn't consider the outcome of 3 at all, so it ought just as well tell you the probability an outcome of 2 appears before an outcome of (say) 6.  Does it?

Answer (score 8):

The event that you observe a $2$ before observing a $3$ (in short, a "win") is comprised of two disjoint events:

1. You immediately observe a $2$ on the current roll.  Let this chance be $p_2.$
2. You do not observe a $2$ or $3$ now (let this chance be $p_0$) *and* you win on subsequent rolls.

Write $p$ for the chance of winning.  Because in situation (2) $p$ does not change for the subsequent rolls, the probability axioms imply

$$p = p_2 + p_0 p.$$

Solving,

$$p = \frac{p_2}{1 - p_0}.$$

You have already computed $p_2$ in the question.

I leave it to you to compute $p_0.$  The easiest way is to compute $p_3,$ the chance of rolling an absolute difference of $3,$ which (by yet another probability axiom) determines $p_0 = 1 - (p_2+p_3),$ whence

$$p = \frac{p_2}{p_2+p_3}.$$

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a particular distribution for this. I have sketched a derivation from first principles.

If we have a sequence of absolute differences of die rolls $D_1, D_2, D_3, \cdots$ (which can take values 0-5), the chance of a 2 appearing before a 3 in a sequence is

$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{2 appears before 3}) =& P[D_1 = 2] + P[D_1 \ne (2,3),D_2=2] + \\&P[D_1 \ne (2,3), D_2 \ne (2,3), D_3 = 2] + \cdots\\
=& P[D_1 = 2] + P[D_1 \ne (2,3)]\cdot P[D_2=2] + \cdots \\
=& \sum_{j=0}^\infty p_2 p_{!2,3}^j \\
=& p_2 \sum_{j=0}^\infty p_{!2,3}^j \\
=& p_2 \left(1 + \sum_{j=1}^\infty p_{!2,3}^j\right)\\
=& p_2 \left(1 + \frac{1}{1-p_{!2,3}} \right)
\end{align}
$$

$p_2$ and $p_{!2,3}$ can be easily worked out "brute force" by looking at all the combinations that the differences can take. With fair die, it works out to be about 0.59.

Assumptions and notation:

- line 1: the chance of a 2 before 3 is:

  - you get 2 on the first roll pair, or
  - you get 2 on the second roll pair, and not 2 nor 3 on the first
  - you get 2 on the third roll pair, and not 2 nor 3 on the first/second
  - etc.
- line 2: all die rolls are independent
- line 3: define $p_2 = P[D = 2]$, define $p_3 = P[D \neq (2,3)]$ where $D$ is an arbitrary difference
- line 6: using a result about the limit of an infinite summation, see "Power Series" section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series

Comment: This becomes *much* simpler to analyze when you consider the natural recursion.